# Xcodebuild Cocoa touch framework code sign error

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, frameworks, code-signing

I have got below error when trying to build project contains sub project which generates cocoa touch framework using xcodebuild command. 
"FrameworkName does not support provisioning profiles" . I don't want to set "Automatic code sigining". So my question is do I need to code sign the framework?

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need to codesign the framework. You only need to code sign the app target. The 'General' tab of your nested framework should look like this: [image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with teamid. No need to specify teamid.